# How to create separate csv file for each sql query in python?

Tags: python

I have 3 sql queries in different files. I tried to run all sql queries one by one. but output of every sql query is saving in single csv file. so i want to save each query result in separate csv file.

```
path1 = "D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/NS dashboard/sql_query/*.txt"
files = glob.glob(path1)
for name in files:
    try:
        with open(name) as f:
            sql_query = f.read()
            cur.execute(sql_query)
            result = cur.fetchall()

            with open("output.csv", 'w') as fp:
                a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
                a.writerow([i[0] for i in cur.description])
                a.writerows(result)

    except:
        print("error")
```

Comment: CSV's are written to the same file because you open them with the same `open("output.csv", 'w')` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because you overwrite the same csv every time.

```
path1 = "D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/NS dashboard/sql_query/*.txt"
files = glob.glob(path1)
i = 1
for name in files:
    try:
        with open(name) as f:
            sql_query = f.read()
            cur.execute(sql_query)
            result = cur.fetchall()

            with open("output_%s.csv" % i, 'w') as fp:
                a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
                a.writerow([i[0] for i in cur.description])
                a.writerows(result)
            i+=1

    except:
        print("error")
```

Comment: thank you for the help. i need one more requirement. If i want to to generate csv file like query name e.g. - if "survey_cust.txt" query runs then csv file will be generate the name like "survey_cust.csv". how to do this, can you please help me to implement this logic?

Comment: @amisha
`csv_name = name.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0] 
with open("output_%s.csv" % csv_name, 'w') as fp:`

Answer (score 0):

You keep writing to the same CSV file. Why don't you try something like this:

```py
path1 = "D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/NS dashboard/sql_query/*.txt"
files = glob.glob(path1)
file_list = ["file1.csv", "file2.csv"]

for iterator, name in enumerate(files):
    try:
        with open(name) as f:
            sql_query = f.read()
            cur.execute(sql_query)
            result = cur.fetchall()

            with open(file_list[iterator], 'w') as fp:
                a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
                a.writerow([i[0] for i in cur.description])
                a.writerows(result)

    except:
        print("error")
```